# Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Reporting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (Are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, .net-assembly

I downloaded this project and database but when I run it I get this error, Can you please help me to fix this? I really appreciate your help.

I have attached the source code and database, please take a look.
https://gofile.io/d/9TZvQV
Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzzdl.jpg)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;

namespace DBApplication
{
    public partial class frmBilling : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        SqlCommand com;
        SqlDataReader dreader;
        DataSet ds;
        DataTable dt;
        DataRow dr;
        string sql;
        int quantity;
        ReportDataSource rds;
        ReportParameterCollection repParams;
        public frmBilling()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString();
            con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            loadCategory();
        }

        private void loadCategory()
        {
            sql = "SELECT CategoryID,CategoryName FROM Categories";
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Categories");
            dt = ds.Tables["Categories"];
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "-1";
            dr[1] = "--Select Category--";
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
            cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
            cmbCategory.ValueMember = "CategoryID";
            cmbCategory.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverlfow. I am not going to that *humpty dumpty* file sharing site, paste the relevant code and error (***NOT IMAGES***) into the question. also see [ask]

Comment: try install the nuget `Install-Package Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.v11 -Version 1.0.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the advice from Michael and my test on your project, please install -nuget package `Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.v11` to solve your problem.

[image]